# How can I add a date and time clock to a website?

Tags: javascript, html, date, datetime

I need to add a date and time clock to a website. It should display the date and time in a very specific format, taking up two lines and using an intended timezone of GMT-4; for example:

> Sat, Mar 23 2019
>   10:33:56 PM

This happens to be for a school project, but I have limited knowledge of Javascript. I've tried looking up some examples and have found some interesting stuff, but I'm unable to adapt those examples to generate the output in the desired format.

Comment: Have you checked out the [MDN docs for the JS Date object methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Date.prototype_Methods)

Answer (score 2):

Please Try This

```js
function display_c(){
   var refresh=1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
   mytime=setTimeout('display_ct()',refresh)
}

function display_ct() {
  var CDate = new Date()
  var NewDate=CDate.toDateString(); 
  NewDate = NewDate + " - " + CDate.toLocaleTimeString();
  document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = NewDate;
  display_c();
}
```

```html
<html>
<head> </head>

<body onload=display_ct();>
  <span id='ct' ></span>
</body>
</html>
```

For Change Date Or Time Format Please Refer this [link](https://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/clock.php)

Comment: Read more about it here: https://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/clock.php :/ copy&paste

Answer (score 0):

> You can add an HTML to your the `body` of your document:

---

> Also, you can add a JavaScript similar to this before `</body>`:

#### Code:

```js
function clock(){
    window.rt=1000;r=0;
    document.getElementById('t-0').textContent=new Date().toLocaleDateString(); // today
    var m=setInterval(function(){
        if(r>84600){clearInterval(m);}
        r++;
        document.getElementById('t-2').textContent=new Date().toLocaleTimeString(); // clock
    }, window.rt);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <title>Clock</title>
    <body onload="clock();">

        <div style="text-align:center;">
            
            <b id="t-0">00/00/0000</b>
            ⏰
            <b id="t-2">00:00:00</b>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get currentDate by `toDateString()` method and get current time by `toLocaleTimeString` and append both in your `DOM` . And call this every `1000` ms to get updated value .

```js
function callDateTime(){
    var currentDate=(new Date()).toDateString();
    var currentTime=(new Date()).toLocaleTimeString(); 
    document.getElementById('watch').innerHTML=`${currentDate}-${currentTime}`;
  }
  
 
setInterval(function(){  callDateTime() }, 1000);
```

```html
<p id="watch"></p>
```